# GMAP3 InfoWindows won't close on iOS browser

Tags: ios, infowindow, jquery-gmap3

I'm using gmap3 jQuery plugin to create an embedded Google Map with markers. When markers are clicked, they display an infowindow. The close X button of the infowindow doesn't work on iPhone and iPad (works well in any desktop browser).

How I can solve?

The site is www.genovaperte.it (it is protected by HTTP Basic AUTH, please use username = webcompany password = webcompany)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your event listener action from 'click' to 'mousedown'. Worked for me.

Comment: It worked. I also had to set z-index to a different value (1000) and reduce the infobox width because on iPhone the X was too near to the right side of the display, and the touchscreen won't work in this area.